# ASP.NET Core MVCでModel層にDIを行いたい

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, asp.net-core

ASP.NET Core MVC（.NET 5）においてDIは、Controllerのコンストラクタインジェクションと、Viewのインジェクションをサポートしています。

Applicationの構成が下記のような階層を持っており、Skinny Controller, Fat Modelのパターンを適用している場合を想定します。
Controller → Service → Models → Entity

Serviceの処理などもテストの対象にしたい場合、Model層にDatabaseContextをDIできるのが理想的だと考えています。この場合、どのような方法をとるのがスマートでしょうか。

ControllerにDatabaseContextをDIして、Service → Modelsと引き渡すしかないでしょうか。

Comment: ASP.NET Core での DI 機能は、Controller, View 以外にもサービス、ミドルウェア、カスタム Tag ヘルパーその他カスタムクラスにも実装できます。Model ⊂ カスタムクラスなのでコンストラクタ経由での DI なら可能なはずです。そのやり方では使えないということですか？　どのように使うつもりなのですか？

Comment: 私が何か大きな勘違いをしているかもしれないので、該当するマニュアルなど参考になる情報をいただけないでしょうか？通常Custom ModelはServiceからnewするか、Serviceに渡されたものを使うか（つまりControllerからServiceに渡されたものを使う＝Controllerへのコンストラクタインジェクション）ぐらいだと考えていました。それ以外の方法では、DIではなくService Locatorパターンぐらいしかないかと思っています。

Comment: http://surferonwww.info/BlogEngine/post/2021/01/01/dependency-injection-for-dotnet-core-application.aspx ←参考になりませんか？

Comment: ありがとうございます。大変参考になりました。ServiceProviderからDIを必要としてるModelを生成することでModelへのDIを実現している感じですね。

Comment: 私がすっかり勘違いしていたようです。DIの連鎖みたいな感じで実装できる（特に複雑なことを考える必要はない）ということで納得しました。WebSurferさんの最初のコメントが的確な表現でした。回答の内容を考えて投稿したら解決済みとしたいと思います。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

結論：普通にDIできる。

Service → Model → Repository といった構成の場合は下記のようにDIの連鎖が作られていれば、ControllerにDIされる際に、下層にもDIが行われる。

**[Startup.cs]**

```csharp
// DIの登録
services.AddTransient<IService, SampleService>();
services.AddTransient<IModel, SampleModel>();
services.AddTransient<IRepository, SampleRepository>();
```

**[DIController.cs]**

```csharp
public class DIController : Controller
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Controller InjectionでDIされるサービス
    /// </summary>
    private readonly IService service;

    /// <summary>
    /// コンストラクタ
    /// </summary>
    public DIController(IService service)
    {
        this.service = service;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// DIテスト
    /// </summary>
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        service.Doing();
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
}
```

**[SampleService.cs]**

```csharp
public class SampleService : IService
{
    private readonly IModel model;

    public SampleService(IModel model)
    {
        this.model = model;
    }

    public void Doing()
    {
        model.Store();
    }
}
```

**[SampleModel.cs]**

```csharp
public class SampleModel : IModel
{
    private readonly IRepository repository;

    public SampleModel(IRepository repository)
    {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    public void Store()
    {
        repository.Insert();
    }
}
```

**[SampleRepository.cs]**

```csharp
public class SampleRepository : IRepository
{
    public void Insert()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("INSERT INTO DB");
    }
}
```